# Structure group of a bundle on the variety obtained by resolution of singular variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

If $X$ is a three dimensional singular complete Calabi-Yau variety over $\mathbb{C}$ whose only singularity is a node $pt$ and $X \setminus pt$ is an non-compact Calabi-Yau Manifold, we suppose there is a small resolution, i.e. replacing $pt$ by a $\mathbb{P}^1$,
\begin{equation}
\pi:\widetilde{X}\rightarrow X
\end{equation}
where $\widetilde{X}$ is a complete Calabi-Yau. $V$ is a rank 5 complex vector bundle on $X$ such that the structure group of $V|_{X \setminus pt}$ could be reduced to $SU(5)$. We know $V$ pulls back to a bundle $\widetilde{V}$ on the smooth Calabi-Yau $\widetilde{X}$, could the structure group of $\widetilde{V}$ be reduced to $SU(5)$?